# Packaging brew'd software in my App

Tags: objective-c, bundle, homebrew

I would like to include some open-source software with an OSX app. This software (e.g. Tesseract) lists that the way to install it on OSX is via Homebrew. But I need to distribute it to my users and can't have them install it separately, but would need it to be bundled in the app's bundle.

How do I do that?

Comment: Apart from the binary, what other files does Tesseract need in order to work?

Comment: @trojanfoe I don't know. I guess there are some language data files, but I guess this is part of the question.

Comment: I'm not sure anyone could be bothered to compile Tesseract in order to see what 3rd-party libraries it needs and other support files.  If you are going to bundle it with your app then you will end up supporting it, so you need to get your hands dirty and work out what files it needs.  If it does need support files then your best hope is that you can specify the location on the command line.  If the path is compiled in and cannot be overridden then you have a problem.